# PullToRefresh TableView inside UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've got a *UIViewController* which is also the *UITableViewDelegate*, amongst other things, for a *UITableView*, created in FirstView.xib

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <
    UITextFieldDelegate, 
    UITableViewDelegate, 
    UITableViewDataSource
> {

UITableView *searchResults; // this is the property for the table view
...
```

}

I want this table view to make use of PullToRefresh: https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh, but the documentation there only explains how to make use of the class as a sub class of the view controller

```
#import "PullRefreshTableViewController.h"

@interface DemoTableViewController : PullRefreshTableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *items;
}
```

My app uses a Tab bar as the root view controller, can anyone explain to me how I can make the **UITableView** into a PullRefreshTableView? When I don't have a **UITableViewController** to edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret is in the scroll view delegate methods which you can already respond to since you are acting as the tables delegate. This [article](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/12/how-to-make-a-pull-to-reload-tableview-just-like-tweetie-2/) provides a good start to create your own pull to refresh.

- `- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` 

  This will let you know when the user starts dragging the scrollview  so you can begin checking whether to refresh or not.
- `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

  This allows you to make necessary transitions while scrolling (mainly swapping text and flipping the arrow)
- `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
               willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate`

  This is where you decide if the user has dragged far enough down to start the refresh.

Comment: Ah that'll do it, I'll handle it myself

Comment: how to use that solution with the leah's pull to refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [this API](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh)

It works fine with UIViewController