# PullRefreshTableViewController subclass inside UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I'm having [this same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500130/pulltorefresh-tableview-inside-uiviewcontroller) with PullRefreshTableViewController.

Basically, I don't know how to correctly instance a tableviewcontroller that is a subclass of PullRefreshTableViewController.

I can do this in the implementation file of a UIViewController:

```
PullRefreshTableViewController *table = [[PullRefreshTableViewController alloc] init];
```

But I can't set the frame like this:

```
table.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,300);
```

or set the delegate or datasource of the "supposed" tableviewcontroller

the code above gives me the error that frame is not a valid property, even PullRefreshTableViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController.

So, I'm I doing something wrong? How can I treat PullRefreshTableViewController like a UITableViewController?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it a subclass of UITableViewController and Controller doesnot has frame property. Instead you can set the frame of tableView of UITableViewController.
Thus ..

```
table.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,300);
```

will work fine in your case.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great, didn't realize that. Also thanks to user barley.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set frame to ViewControllers. You set frame to Views. So it should be

```
self.table.view.frame = CGRectMake(...)
```